# Expression works in one QGIS project, but not another

Tags: qgis, polygon, aggregation, qgs, qgsexpression

I have an expression in a Print Layout that populates a label with an attribute, based on which polygons are selected in map view. In the QGIS project that I made, it works perfectly. I tried copying and pasting the expression into a different project and changed the layer name and field, but it now just returns `''`.

I even tried copying the shapefile and expression from the original project, but in the new project, it does not work.

The expression is as follows:

```sql
aggregate(
  layer:='LR_POLY_SAMPLE',
  aggregate:='concatenate_unique',
  expression:=Name,
  concatenator:=', ',
  filter:=is_selected() is true
  )
```

The project properties and shapefile properties are identical.

I'd appreciate any help as to why the expression is now returning `''` when it is all exactly the same. QGIS version: 3.30.0

Comment: Please provide example data, otherwise this is pure guessing. If not possible, double- and triple-check layer and attribute names.

Comment: The layer names and attribute names are all the same, I dragged the layer from one project to another, and copied and pasted the expression - so essentially duplicated the project, however in the second project the expression does not work which is what's confusing me.

Comment: Do you have features selected?

Comment: I applied a symbology rule that also checks when the features are selected to make sure. The polygons are changing colour in accordance with the rule but still the other expression returns a blank result.

Comment: As mentioned: without a project with (dummy) data, it's difficult to solve the problem.

Comment: Try ` concatenate_unique(name)` - does this work? If that works, expand the expression with the filter condition and if this works, use the `aggregate` function. Expand your expression step by step to see where the error happens.

Comment: Unfortunately as it is an expression in the Print Layout I need the expression to point to the target layer - is there a way I can do this with the concatenate_unique?

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem in the first new layout in an unsaved project. The layout had *only* a Label Item. After I added a Map Item, the expression worked (even after I subsequently deleted the map item). Perhaps try adding a new map item to force the layout to recognise the map layers, and hopefully you can delete it again. I can't guarantee it will work, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Unfortunately I'd already tried adding a map, I even added the map before the label and expression, and still was just returning a blank result. I ended up finding a workaround for it, as for some reason making a virtual field in the table and then just printing the values in that field worked rather than doing the expression in the print layout. But I appreciate everyone's efforts to help solve this.